# CKEditor inserts &nbsp; after smileys

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor in a social network project, and I thought it would be nice to have the Smileys plugin..

However, when I add a smiley though the UI, using the Smiley button, CKEditor autmatically inserts &nbsp after each smiley causing them to not get parsed.

I've tried to disable fillEmptyBlocks in config.js and that didn't work, and also tried replacing &nbsp on the serverside with PHP's:

```
str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $text);
```

and oddly enough that didn't work either.

Can I somehow replace them in CKEditor before passing the text to the server, or is there a better solution for this?

Have been trying to fix this for a long time now, so a fix would be greatly(!) appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Weird. No answers or anything.

Anyway... I found out that because my content is UTF-8 encoded, a non breaking space is not "xA0", but "\xC2\xA0". Here's a fix for people getting to this question through Google:

```
// Replace &nbsp; with PHP before outputting
preg_replace('/\xC2\xA0/', ' ', $text);
```

Still looking for a better solution though.